# Is it possible to combine small queries into single query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have the following queries:

```
var truckCount = await DbContext.Trucks
    .Where(t => t.Departure == null)
    .CountAsync();

var firstTruck = await DbContext.Trucks
    .Where(t => t.Departure == null)
    .MinAsync(t => t.Arrival);

var railcarCount = await DbContext.Railcars
    .Where(r => r.Departure == null)
    .CountAsync();

var firstRailcar = await DbContext.Railcars
    .Where(t => t.Departure == null)
    .MinAsync(t => t.Arrival);
```

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to combine these queries into one so that there is only one round trip to the database?

I'd be looking to generate a query something like this.

```
select
    (select count(*) from Trucks where Departure is null) as TruckCount,
    (select min(Arrival) from Trucks where Departure is null) as FirstTruck,
    (select count(*) from Railcars where Departure is null) as RailcarCount,
    (select min(Arrival) from Railcars where Departure is null) as FirstRailcar
```

My backend is SQL Server.

Comment: These are different queries, so how you expect that they could be translated to a single query? If you need that you have to write a SP which gives you these information as output parameters. But then you will have still multiple queries in the DB

Comment: @TimSchmelter: SQL Server supports subqueries.

Comment: There are third-party libraries that enable EF queries in batches.

Comment: @JonathanWood: maybe you can use the EF extended library with its future queries: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended But i see its no longer supported since 2015, they recommend paid libraries like https://entityframework-extensions.net/?z=ef-extended

Comment: Roundtrips to the database are *rarely* significant. You'd achieve more benefits from scanning the tables only once (`SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(Arrival) FROM Trucks WHERE Departure IS NULL`). Note that subqueries will not do this either, at least not the way they've been written here. They are potentially still faster than individual queries as parallel scans can benefit from each other, but that's still not as good as dividing the work properly. (Of course this is assuming both queries would benefit from the same indexes, which seems likely here but is not necessarily the case.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Are you saying the SQL I posted wouldn't be faster than four separate queries? Seems like it could potentially be a noticeable difference to me. I'd be happy to incorporate your revised SQL, but don't see anyway to duplicate that from Entity Framework either.

Comment: The answer is, as always, "it depends". If the tables are small and/or the DB is very fast and/or the network is slow, you may notice the roundtrip times of four queries vs. one, but this is not likely. If the server has lots of resources available for parallelization, your "naive" approach to stuffing all the queries into one may be faster than four separate queries, but it will still not be as good as actually minimizing the total number of table scans. So would it be faster, yes it might be, will it be an order of magnitude faster, not necessarily.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: But the four separate queries would also have more table scans. I'm not seeing any way around that short of writing a stored procedure or raw SQL.

Comment: Correct. "There ain't no such thing as a free lunch", as the saying goes. This particular optimization is rather specific, not necessarily always a good idea to do blindly, and not something easily built into an ORM layer. There's nothing wrong with writing raw SQL to speed up specific scenarios *if* they've proven to be bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a third party library which enables to execute multiple queries in a single roundtrip to the database. Maybe [this extension](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended) with it's future queries works for you.

Otherwise you could implement a stored-procedure which encapsulates the queries (as subqueries) and returns the desired information.

Another option might be to just use 2 queries instead of 4:

```
var truckInfo = await DbContext.Trucks
    .GroupBy(t => t.Departure == null)
    .Where(g => g.Key == true)
    .Select(g => new { Count = g.Count(), FirstTruck = g.Min(t => t.Arrival) })
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync() ?? new { Count = 0, FirstTruck = DateTime.MinValue };

   // same for Railcars
```

Comment: Actually [this extension](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) can generate exactly the same query as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Not with linq, no. Why? Because of two reasons:

1. Query syntax has no way to get count and use union to get from one query
2. Method count, is immediate execution and not deferred, so you can't chain into one query

To be honest, that would be difficult to achieve even with a sql query as the data has different data types and columns.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted what the SQL query might look like.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, there is EF Core extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators) which can run this query and almost any SQL ANSI query via LINQ

```cs
using var db = DbContext.CreateLinqToDBConnection();

var trucks = DbContext.Trucks
    .Where(t => t.Departure == null);

var railcars = DbContext.Railcars
    .Where(r => r.Departure == null);

var result = await db.SelectAsync(() => new 
{
    TruckCount = trucks.Ccount(),
    FirstTruck = trucks.Min(t => t.Arrival),
    RailcarCount = railcars.Count(),
    FirstRailcar = railcars.Min(t => t.Arrival)
});
```